# How activate ng-class only on one element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `ng-repeat` and `ng-class` for each element. I use it for selecting elements (add border for selected).

```
<div class="main-block_channel_create">
<section class="parent_messageList cancelDelete">
    <div id="section_animate" class="messagesList_block cancelDelete" infinite-scroll='messagelist.nextSet()' infinite-scroll-listen-for-event='anEvent' infinite-scroll-distance='100'>
        <!-- User Images List -->
        <a href="" class="messageBl message_preview animated" ng-repeat='preview in messagelist.previewList'>
            <div class="image_container_preview" ng-class="{community_select: item.isSelected}" ng-click='communitySelect(preview)' attr="{{preview.preview_id}}">
                <img class="deleteMessageBtn" src="images/close_icon.svg" ng-click="deleteMessage(preview.message_id)">
                <div class="spinner_container">
                    <!--<img src="/images/logo-80.svg" class='spinner_img'>-->
                    <img class="spinner_logo_vertical" src="images/logo_vertical-part.svg" alt="">
                    <img class="spinner_logo_left" src="images/logo_left-part.svg" alt="">
                    <img class="spinner_logo_right" src="images/logo_right-part.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <img class="message_preview-image" src="{{preview.image}}" alt="">
                <!--  Tсли нет изображения — показываем текст -->
                <div class="message_preview-text MediumNormalJunior" ng-if="!preview.image">
                    <div class="message_preview-text-inner" ng-if='preview.name'>
                        {{preview.name}}
                    </div>
                    <!-- если нету и текста показываем empty-->
                </div>
                <div class="empty_message" ng-if='!preview.text && !preview.image'>
                     <!--<h4>Empty</h4> -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="stats" ng-show='preview.total_score > 0'>
                <p>{{preview.total_score}}</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <footer class="listFooter">

        </footer>
    </div>
</section>
```

sass

```
.community_select
    border: 3px solid white
```

directive

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

angular
    .module('buzz')
    .directive('channelcreate', channelcreate);

function channelcreate($rootScope, $location, $timeout, $cookies, $window, communityApiService, getCommunities){

    return{
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: '/templates/channelCreate/channelCreate.html',
        link: function($scope){
            // $rootScope.showChannelCreate = null;

            // Select communities for create new channel
            $scope.communityList = [];
            $scope.communitySelect = function(communityId){
                $scope.selected = false;
                if ($scope.communityList.indexOf(communityId) == -1){
                    $scope.communityList.push(communityId);

                } else {
                    $scope.communityList.pop(communityId)
                }

                console.log($scope.communityList);
            };

            // all messages preview are loaded from messagesLoadFactory
            $scope.messagelist = new getCommunities();

        }
    };
};

})();
```

I can identify each div by `id` when it is clicked. How can I change only one element, but not all of them?

Comment: Can you post how you  use the directive in the HTML? I don't see any element `<channelcreate>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your login... an option can be to check if the element's id is in the list of selected elements with `communityList.indexOf(preview.id) != -1` so your `ng-class` would look like:

```
ng-class="{community_select: communityList.indexOf(preview.id) != -1}"
```

### Edit

Also, when deleting an `id` from the `$scope.communityList` make sure you first find its index and then remove it with [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Now the portion for removing/adding the `id` would look like this:

```
// ... content omitted
$scope.communitySelect = function(communityId) {
  $scope.selected = false;
  var index = $scope.communityList.indexOf(communityId);
  if (index == -1) {
    $scope.communityList.push(communityId);
  } else {
    $scope.communityList.splice(index, 1)
    //                          ^^^    ^
    //        remove    starting_here  one_element
  }

  console.log($scope.communityList);
};
// ... content omitted
```

Comment: Sure, test variable it's only example)) So... i've add it in my code, announced communityList across $scope. But it doesn't work

Comment: @maximus could you edit the question and add some more context, i.e: the ng-repeat code in the HTML?

Comment: @maximus, also, if you could post the whole directive it could help

Comment: But have very interesting bug.When select several objects in a row. They light up. For example three blocks are highlighted. If click on the block that was highlighted first, the border is removed from the last one added.

Comment: @maximus, that's because you're doing this: `$scope.communityList.pop(communityId)`. [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the last element in the collection. You have to find the index of the element and then remove it. See my answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to keep selection on screen to highlighted, for the same I don't think so you need to maintain extra collection list. Rather you can add flag `isSelected` on that record and toggle it based on user click.

**HTML**

I have and ng-repeat and ng-class for each element. I use it for selecting elements (add border for selected).

```
<a href="" class="messageBl message_preview animated" 
  ng-repeat='preview in messagelist.previewList'>
    <div class="image_container_preview" 
     ng-class="{community_select: item.isSelected}" 
     ng-click='communitySelect(preview)' 
     attr="{{preview.preview_id}}">
</a>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.communitySelect = function(communityId) {
  item.isSelected = !item.isSelected;
};
```

And whenever you need list of selected previews, you can easily loop over the `previews` collection and grab those ones who have `isSelected` flag ticked.

```
var selected = $scope.previews.map(i => i.isSelected);
```

Comment: There is something you could tweak in this code: `ng-click='communitySelect(preview)' ` passes as argument a `preview` (whole object containing the `id`) and `$scope.communitySelect = function(communityId) {
  item.isSelected = !item.isSelected;
};` is expecting a `communityId` (id property of `preview`?), despite it is not used, anyway.

Comment: I've got some error 
`Cannot create property 'isSelected' on number '13'`
pass id value, not object

Comment: check updated answer, you should change from `ng-click='communitySelect(preview.id)'` to  `ng-click='communitySelect(preview)'`

Comment: @Pankaj i pass object, not only id. I can't understand where we get variable `isSelected`? Because in `messagelist.previewList` i don't have it.

Comment: @Pang my bad. I don't know how that came. I removed it. Thanks for heads up.